# How many users can I create in ADB2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I recently started studying ADB2C.
Therefore, I would like to know the maximum number of users I can register with ADB2C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 50M+ users. You do not need to contact Microsoft. AAD B2C tenants auto scale for number of objects.
You are not charged for users. You are charged for unique authentications per month.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft will happily bill you for as many users as you want past the 50,000 free threshold. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/external-identities/

Comment: Is there no limit to the number of users I can register if I pay for it?Sorry for My Bad English

Comment: ah, looks like there are soft limits. read the resources section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-service-limits-restrictions) and note, *.To go beyond the default quota, you must contact Microsoft Support*